# I want mvn test to run a sh file before running the unit tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have e2e tests using selenium that I am trying to incorporate into our build process. I was going to have the server act as the hub. I have a sh file that when executed runs the selenium standalone server jar.

This issue is I have to manually run the sh file be doing mvn test. How would I configure maven to run the file before the tests?

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Usually it does not make sense to run end-to-end tests before unit tests..cause unit tests are the lowest level of testing...next can be a kind of integration tests where you can count end-to-end test with it...furthermore you can run them within Maven..maven has steps for the pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test...which can be done using the maven-failsafe-plugin...using selenium...

Comment: @khmarbaise The current project already properly integrated unit tests and e2e tests. But the current e2e tests are being replaced with a complete solution. I've been replacing the old tests with the new one which has it's own pom.xml file so you just have cd to the project directory and run the maven test. I'll look more into the maven lifecycle to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as part of plugin in pom.xml file of MVN.

One example here

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.test.shellscript</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>script-runner</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>script.sh</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This looks like something I can do. I'll report back